# Sharing char pointers in C structs using shm_open

Tags: c, arrays, struct, shared-memory

noob alert with C here.

I have a struct as such

```
typedef struct {
    char* name
} info;
```

And storing an array (size 10) of this struct (in another struct called `table`) in a shared memory object using the shm_open call:

```
int fd = shm_open("someName", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
if (fd < 0) {
     fd = shm_open("someName", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
     if (fd < 0) {
         printf("ERROR: Could not open shared memory space\n");
         return -1;
     }
}
(*tables) = mmap(NULL, sizeof(table), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
ftruncate(fd, sizeof(table));
close(fd);
```

However, the issue that I have is that later through the code such a scenario happens:
If process B runs this and puts some text, say "foo" in the `name` field of an element of the `table` array, process A does not have access to that `char*`.
All it sees is a memory address, but not the actual content of the `char*` as opposed to if it wrote the content itself. However, I would also like to note that if I replace `char*` with a fixed size `char[]`, say `char name[20]` instead of `char *name`, then this issue does not occur.

I would like to know whether there is any way around this, and if not, why is it so?

Thank you!

Comment: Pointers are *local to the current process*. Even if you have a pointer to shared memory, the shared memory may not be mapped to the same address in different processes. Don't pass pointers through IPC, pass the *data*, the *contents* that the pointers are pointing to.

Comment: So would you suggest any way to remove the limit on the character count of my field and still be able to share it?

Comment: How would you pass the data in this case?

Comment: you can share whatever you dump to the shared memory.

Comment: First of all, what is the *purpose* of the exercise? What is the *use-case*? Perhaps you should reconsider the IPC primitive you're using? Perhaps communicate through pipes instead? Or perhaps you need to actually enforce limits, so you can have arrays instead of pointers?

Comment: Well it's an assignment on a course and its purpose is for us to learn how to use `shm_open` for sharing memory and then use semaphores for synchronization. Sadly I cannot change my method of inter-process communication for this!

Comment: And if using `shm_open` there's no better way to do this, I will be okay with enforcing the limit but I was just curious as to whether there's a cleaner way to do it without limiting the field length :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using shared memory for IPC, all of the data to be shared, must be located in shared memory. It's that simple, there's no way around it. What you can do however for some larger, more variable chunks of data, is simply allocate a dedicated shared memory chunk for that data, and provide its name via the master table. Another option in your case is to arrange for the shared memory to be sufficiently larger than your `info` struct, such that `name` is just an offset from that address, to where the name data resides.  Then address of data is `&name + *name'.